# change control outside UpdatePanel

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel

**In short:**  I want to enable a button i.e. outside UpdatePanel when I click on a button from inside UpdatePanel.

**Problem:** The button enables but tags `i`  and `asp:Localize` are not showing in the rendered code after button click from `UpdatePanel updPnlOfferings`

**Detail:** 
I have a DataList inside `UpdatePanel` which contains delete button for every item in the list. delete button is firing an event on server which deletes the record and disables a button (i.e. outside of the UpdatePanel. 

 As someone suggested I kept my button(which need to be disabled) in `UpdatePanel` below

```
  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updPnlCourse" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDeleteCourseDetails" runat="server" OnClick="lnkDeleteCourseDetails_Click">
                        <i class="icon-remove-sign"></i>
                        <asp:Localize ID="Localize6" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:CBLabels, LBL_DeleteDetails %>" />
                    </asp:LinkButton>
                    <asp:ConfirmButtonExtender ID="lnkDeleteCourseDetails_ConfirmButtonExtender" runat="server"
                        ConfirmText='Are you sure you want to delete this course?' Enabled="True" TargetControlID="lnkDeleteCourseDetails">
                    </asp:ConfirmButtonExtender>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

The Main `UpdatePanel` which is firing the event is below

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updPnlOfferings" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Panel ID="pnlDSOfferings" runat="server">
                <asp:DataList ID="dtlstOfferings" runat="server" OnItemCommand="dtlstOfferings_ItemCommand" EnableViewState="true">
                </asp:DataList></asp:Panel>
         </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

on `dtlstOfferings_ItemCommand` event I coded this

```
lnkDeleteCourseDetails.Enabled = true;
lnkDeleteCourseDetails.ToolTip = "";
lnkDeleteCourseDetails_ConfirmButtonExtender.Enabled = true;
updPnlCourse.Update();
```

Comment: What problem are you getting? Is it not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known problem as specified in this [link](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/718810/linkbutton-controls-collection-lost-on-postback).
The solution is to put all your content that are there inside the LinkButton, within a place holder like below, or make all the child controls as server controls.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDeleteCourseDetails" runat="server" OnClick="lnkDeleteCourseDetails_Click">
   <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server"> 
     <i class="icon-remove-sign"></i>
     <asp:Localize ID="Localize6" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:CBLabels, LBL_DeleteDetails %>" />
   </asp:PlaceHolder>
</asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: Wow. You saved me. I have been banging my head on desk until now. Thanks Alot.